# Elastic Search Query (a like x and y) or (b like x and y)

Tags: elasticsearch

Some background info: In the bellow example user searched for "HTML CSS". I split each word from the search string and created the SQL query seen bellow.

Now I am trying to make an elastic search query that has the same logic as the following SQL query:

```
SELECT  
     title, description  
FROM `classes` 
WHERE 
    (`title` LIKE '%html%' AND `title` LIKE '%css%') OR 
    (description LIKE '%html%' AND description LIKE '%css%')
```

Currently, half way there but can't seem to get it right yet.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "title": "html"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "title": "css"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "title"
  ],
  "size": 30
}
```

Now I need to find how to add follow logic

```
OR (description LIKE '%html%' AND description LIKE '%css%')
```

One important point is that I need to only fetch documents that have both words in either title or disruption. I don't want to fetch documents that have only 1 word.

I will update questions as I find more info.

Update: The chosen answer also provides a way to boost scoring based on the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try following query. You can use `should` for making `or` operation

```
{
 "query": {
  "bool": {
     "should": [
        {
           "bool": {
              "must": [
                 {
                    "match": {                      // Go for term if your field is analyzed
                       "title": {
                          "query": "html css",
                          "operator": "and",
                          "boost" : 2
                       }
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        },
        {
           "bool": {
              "must": [
                 {
                    "match": {
                       "description": {
                          "query": "html css",
                          "operator": "and"
                       }
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     ],
     "minimum_number_should_match": 1
  }
 },
  "_source": [
    "title",
    "description"
   ]
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working nicely.  I am also trying to find a way to sort in such as way that hits from the title has higher _score than hits from the description. Do you know if that is possible? :-)

Comment: Yes, that is possible. You can boost `title` field.  have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, you been very helpful :-)

Answer (score 2):

I feel most appropriate query to be used in this case is [`multi_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#query-dsl-multi-match-query).

> `multi_match` query is convenient way of running the `same` query on
>   multiple fields.

So your query can be written as:

```
GET /_search
{
  "_source": ["title", "description"],
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "html css",
      "fields": ["title^2", "description"],
      "operator":"and"
    }
  }
}
```

1. `_source` filters the dataset so that only fields mentioned in array
   will be displayed in results.
2. `^2` denotes boosting `title` field with the number 2
3. `operator:and` makes sure that all `terms` in query must be matched
   in either `fields`

Comment: Thank you, but I had to use match_phrase for description as it gave better results in my particular use case. So the selected answer gave me more flexibility. Next time when I write a similar query I will try to use multi_match. Thanks again for your time. I will test the syntax you suggested and if it works I will up vote your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

From the elasticsearch 5.2 doc:
One option is to use the nested datatype instead of the object datatype.

More details here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/nested.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for trying, But nested is used for storing an array of objects in documents. I am trying to create a query with a condition similar to (field a like x and y) or (field b like x and y). Very different use case.